# Jenkins Build, Execute Shell Error

Tags: ruby, git, jenkins, rally

I'm trying to trigger a shell command via Jenkins 2.54 on Build. I've had this running in the past but decided to rebuild my mac 'clean' without TimeMachine..

In the background, i'm using a node.js app for building applications in Agile Central (Rally) - All of this works fine and even the shell command I use runs in the Shell (Fish to be precise).

As far as I can tell I have all the dependancies installed as this works when running from cmd line..

The command I'm using:

> ruby /g2ca/git2ca_agile_central.rb devOps

[image]

As mentioned in the shell directly this does everything I need, takes a commit with an artefact ID such as a user story US01 and adds the expected outcome to the user stories Change Set:

[image]

BUT.. Jenkins throws a fit in it's console:

> + ruby /g2ca/git2ca_agile_central.rb devOps /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in
>   `require': cannot load such file -- vcseif (LoadError)    from
>   /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in`
>   require'     from /g2ca/git2ca_agile_central.rb:35:in `' Build
>   step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure

I'm no professional coder by any stretch!!! So go easy here as I could be way out of my depth, but this is baffling me..

I'm using Brew also, if it helps here is the output from

> Brew Config

HOMEBREW_VERSION: 1.1.12

ORIGIN: https://github.com/Homebrew/brew.git

HEAD: 8ea778f7c7ea790694485030d105a92a9416ef33

Last commit: 9 days ago

Core tap ORIGIN: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core

Core tap HEAD: 55a35bb74627e9eee9537dc726ac07c3dbc59444

Core tap last commit: 7 hours ago

HOMEBREW_PREFIX: /usr/local

HOMEBREW_REPOSITORY: /usr/local/Homebrew

HOMEBREW_CELLAR: /usr/local/Cellar

HOMEBREW_BOTTLE_DOMAIN: https://homebrew.bintray.com

CPU: octa-core 64-bit haswell

Homebrew Ruby: 2.0.0-p648

Clang: 8.1 build 802

Git: 2.11.0 => /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/git

Perl: /usr/bin/perl

Python: /usr/local/bin/python => /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7

Ruby: /usr/local/bin/ruby => /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.4.1_1/bin/ruby

Java: 1.8.0_121

macOS: 10.12.4-x86_64

Xcode: 8.3.1

CLT: N/A

X11: N/A

Do I have a ruby missmatch between my shell and Jenkins??

Here's what i'm using:
RallyConnectorForGit-3.7_3
Node 5.4.1
rally_api 1.2.1
httpclient 2.8.3
vcseif 1.2.0
Jenkins 2.54

I'm lost... Anything else you need please shout!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is fixed was ruby version on HBrew